# how to download into stata several excel sheet each one represents a data set for specific year

Tags: excel, stata, importerror, import-from-excel

am new to stata, this is my first time to use it :(
i have the data set for firms operate in kuwait market for 10 years, from 2013 to 2022, each year in a different excel files. so i have total 10 excel files, which i saved them in one folder, the folder bath "C:\Users\noura\OneDrive\Desktop\project excel"
excel files name:
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022

so how i can import the 10 excel files into Stata and make sure that Stata are reading the data as continues years from 2013 to 2022.

what is the codes i should use?

i tried several code but nothing work

```
// Set the working directory to the folder where your Excel files are saved
cd "C:\Users\noura\OneDrive\Desktop\project excel"

// Loop over each year and import the corresponding Excel file into Stata
foreach file of varlist 2013/2022 {
   import excel "`file'.xlsx", firstrow clear
   gen year = "`file'"
   append using "`file'.xlsx"
}

// Sort the data by year
sort year
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1709284-how-to-download-several-excel-sheet-each-one-represents-a-year

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to a solution. Well done for being your first time using Stata.

The problem in your code is that `clear` in

```
import excel "`file'.xlsx", firstrow clear
```

clears all the data currently in memory. So in each loop you are deleting all previous years. In my modification of your example code I have set up a tempfile that you use to save the data to at the end of each loop. And then you append your year data to that data set.

```
// Set the working directory to the folder where your Excel files are saved
cd "C:\Users\noura\OneDrive\Desktop\project excel"

clear
tempfile allyears
save `allyears', emptyok

// Loop over each year and import the corresponding Excel file into Stata
foreach file of varlist 2013/2022 {
   import excel "`file'.xlsx", firstrow clear
   gen year = "`file'"
   append using `allyears'
   save `allyears', replace
}

// Sort the data by year
sort year
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your help really appreciated. when am using your code, it is showing me 2013 invalid name?
r(198);
and i double check the excel name its correct 2013 and it's in the same folder path, all my excel files are named as the years they are represent (2013 to 2022) and they are in the same folder path "C:\Users\noura\OneDrive\Desktop\project excel". so what i should do to solve this issue. thank you again

Comment: Ah, there is one more issue. `foreach ... of varlist` is only meant to be used when looping over variables in a dataset. Try `forvalues file = 2013/2022 {`.