# Appending Excel files into Stata dataset

Tags: excel, loops, stata

I have several Excel files and I want to `append` them into  one Stata .dta file. I am trying to test my code with only five files (0.xlsx; 1.xlsx; 2.xlsx; 3.xlsx and 4.xlsx). At the end my dataset it is only created as an appended dataset of 0.xlsx and 4.xlsx.

This is the code I have been using.

```
import excel "0.xlsx", firstrow clear
capture save "combined_data.dta", replace

forvalues i = 1/4 {
  import excel "`i'.xlsx", firstrow clear
  append using "combined_data.dta"
}

save "combinedd_data.dta"
```

The Excel files have the same number of columns. Has anyone any advice?

Comment: There is a solution in this answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981383/how-to-download-into-stata-several-excel-sheet-each-one-represents-a-data-set-fo/75983509#75983509

Comment: Each time around the loop, you `append` but do not `save`, and the next `clear` throws away the results. WIth that code you get the contents of the first and last files only in your Stata dataset.